# IDA Pro Debbuger is debugging the original code and not the patched code

Tags: ida, debugging, anti-debugging

Using IDA Pro, I tried to patch `int 2Dh` to `nop`.
However, with the debugger, it seems that the original code is being loaded.
What may be the reason for that? This might be related for some protections? I'm new to RE and to IDA. I did not yet analyze deeply the routines before the `int 2Dh` anti-debug technique.

The view during static analysis is:

[image]

The view during debug is:

[image]

As you may notice, the original `int 2Dh` command has been reverted.

Comment: Have you tried saving the patched executable and then run/debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in ida you use patch byte, patch word, or assemble, the patch is NOT applied to the base executable.
You just  have to go to Edit-> Patch program -> Apply patches to input file.
Then your input file is modified now.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why sometimes I don't have to do this in other programs. Sometimes I just use patch word and the debugger debugs what I've patched.

Comment: Also you have a patched byte window, that show you all applied patches, just in case you didn't know !